# Access to Dynamic constant values

Tags: php, class, session, variables

I have a class named `Error` like the following:

```
class Error
{
    CONST
        ERROR999 =
        [
            'message'               =>              'No admin is found with the supplied email id + password combination.',
            'type'                  =>              'error',
            'sources'               =>              '/admin/login/process',
            'comments'              =>              'Number of records found = 0'
        ],
        ERROR1000 =
        [
            'message'               =>              'Sorry, the requested administrator account has been suspended!',
            'type'                  =>              'error',
            'sources'               =>              '/admin/login/process',
            'comments'              =>              'user.isactive = 0'
        ]
}
```

I get the Constant Variable names (such as `ERROR999`,`ERROR1000` etc. dynamically via a session named `$_SESSION['ERROR_SESSION']`.

My question is how can I get the value of the `ERROR` constants dynamically?

I tried `$$`,`constant('ERROR::'.$_SESSION['ERROR_SESSION')`, but they simply do not work. Error is being thrown in all the cases.

I shall appreciate if you can give me any suggestions or solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
constant('Error::'.$_SESSION[Basic::Error_Session_Name])
```

It is `Error` instead of `ERROR`.

Comment: It is still throwing error. `Warning:  constant(): Couldn't find constant Error::ERROR999`

Comment: shouldnt you define constant using lower case `const`

Comment: also if you under a different namespace, you need to import `Error` class

Comment: I have imported the Error class already (not added the code here). When I try to access the variable as `var_dump(Error::ERROR999);`, it works properly. The problem is I can not access it via dynamic variable name that is being accepted by the session variable.